# Android Studio sqlLite: (1) table Profile has no column named _id in "INSERT INTO Profile(Surname,GPA,_id,Date,Name) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"

Tags: android-sqlite

I'm trying to add a profile object to my sqlLite database, but I'm continuously getting this error. I can't add my object to the table.

I'm expecting to add an my profile properties to my table.

This is the code that receives input from user:

```
        saveProfileButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //receiving string from the editText Block
            String Name=profileNameEditText.getText().toString();
            String Surname=profileSurnameEditText.getText().toString();
            Integer ID =parseInt(profileIDEditText.getText().toString());
            String GPA=profileGPAEditText.getText().toString();

            String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

            DatabaseHelper databaseHelper=new DatabaseHelper(getActivity()); //using get activity instead of this since we're executing this block of code inside a fragment

            //if(!(Name.equals("")) && !(Surname.equals(""))&& !(ID.equals(""))&&!(GPA.equals(""))) // only execute the block if none of the entries are empty

            //{


                databaseHelper.addProfile(new Profile(ID,Name,Surname,GPA,date));`
```

This is the code that adds it to my database:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)  //creating two tables within my database
{
    String CREATE_TABLE_PROFILE = " CREATE TABLE " + Config.PROFILE_TABLE_NAME +
            " (" + Config.COLUMN_PROFILE_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
            + Config.COLUMN_PROFILE_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + Config.COLUMN_PROFILE_SURNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + Config.COLUMN_PROFILE_GPA + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + Config.COLUMN_PROFILE_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL)";

    Log.d(TAG, CREATE_TABLE_PROFILE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_PROFILE); //executes our Profile Table in the SQL database
    //db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ACCESS); //execute our Access Table in SQL database
    Log.d(TAG, "db created");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{

}

public long addProfile(Profile profile)  //adding a profile to the table
{
    long ID=-1;

    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase(); //opening the database to write in it

    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues(); //holds the value we want to store in our database

    //assigning all the profile values to the corresponding column values
    contentValues.put(Config.COLUMN_PROFILE_ID,profile.getID());
    contentValues.put(Config.COLUMN_PROFILE_NAME,profile.getName());
    contentValues.put(Config.COLUMN_PROFILE_SURNAME,profile.getSurname());
    contentValues.put(Config.COLUMN_PROFILE_GPA,profile.getGPA());
    contentValues.put(Config.COLUMN_PROFILE_DATE,profile.getDate());


    try

    {
        ID=db.insertOrThrow(Config.PROFILE_TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);  //inserting content values into database table

    }

    catch(SQLException e)
    {

        Log.d(TAG,"EXCEPTION:"+e);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Operation Failed!:="+e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    finally
    {

        db.close();

    }

    return ID;

}
```

`

Comment: Very often, a **column not found** when it clearly exists in the create SQL, (on Android), is due to the fact that the  **`onCreate`** method, of the class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper **only runs once for the life of the database**. As such changes made to the create SQL will not be reflected. If you can afford to lose any data in the database. The simply uninstall the App and rerun. If you have to preserve data then you would need to increment the database version and provide suitable migration code in the `onUpgrade` method.